# How can I stop Zombies spawning while letting other Mobs spawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

My Friend plays Minecraft, and he doesn't want zombies, drowneds or husks to spawn, but he still wants other mobs to spawn. I've tried `/tp @e[type=zombie] 0 -100 0` to teleport them into the void (with a repeat command block), which works initially, but then as he plays they always come back, which is especially annoying because I can't target the problem (in my test world I've teleported 5000 blocks away and they still don't spawn. Could someone please point out the problem and maybe how to fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: This needs more details, your proposed solution should just work. In what way do they "come back"? Mobs that get teleported to y=-100 are deleted instantly, they can't come back. Please ask your friend how exactly he set this up and if he can reproduce it in a new world.

Comment: @FabianRöling Well, they just keep spawning normally after a while. I could not reproduce it in my own world so I will check with him.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. I guess you should check the basics again, command blocks in loaded chunks, set to repeating and auto, …

Comment: if you really need, in theory you could use, in some repeating command blocks, ``/kill @e[type=zombie]``, ``/kill @e[type=drowned]`` and ``/kill @e[type=husk]``